# How to identify hard drive issues on windows 8.1

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

*required statement* I'm a developer, not an IT admin :)

I'm running `Windows 8.1` and on occasion while downloading relatively large videos (~2.5 GB) the download seems to crawl. I noticed while looking at `Task Manager` that it isn't my network that is toping out but my disk (often between 95 and 100% utilization. This isn't always the case but seems to be happening more often.

So my question (as a non-OS expert) is how would I go about figuring out what might be causing the issue?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Its either your connection is being thorttled by your isp by the type of data your downloading and how your downloading it ( i.e. p2p ) or your hdd can't write the data fast enough which is unlikely unless it needs to be replaced.  But you provided no specifics so I can't say either way.

Comment: Can you recommend a tool that I can use to identify possible issue?

Comment: There does not exist a tool to determine if your ISP throttles your connection, it either happens or it does not, you could in theory try using a VPN and if you a faster connection then you know thats the case.  Like I said its unlikely your HDD.